How to get avoid authentication but get user information using only username and connect to LDAP JNDI Realm using service account
Currently, my app is authenticated and authorized using LDAP. Its a form based authentication when form is submitted 'j_security_check' action is called and connects using JNDI Realm. It uses a service-account/common credentials to connect to server. Below is how my code looks.

I have a html file with submit option

<form name='xyz' action='j_security_check' method='POST'\>
    <input id='c2' name='j_username'\>
    <input id='c2' name='j_password'\>
</form\>


JNDI Realm configuration in tomcat server.xml

<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"  
   connectionName="cn=\common_username\,dc=example,dc=com"
   connectionPassword="\common_password\"
   connectionURL="ldap://localhost:10389"
   roleBase="dc=example,dc=com,dc=ActiveMQ"
   roleName="cn"
   roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
   roleSubtree="true"
   userPattern="cn={0},dc=example,dc=com"
   userSearch="(cn={0})"
 \>


Following changes in web.xml

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection\>
        <web-resource-name\>xyz\</web-resource-name\>
        <url-pattern\>/xyz/\*\</url-pattern\>
        <http-method\>GET\</http-method\>
        <http-method\>POST\</http-method\>
        <http-method\>PUT\</http-method\>
    </web-resource-collection\>
    <auth-constraint\>
        <role-name\>xyz\</role-name\>
    </auth-constraint\>
</security-constraint>
<login-config\>
    <auth-method\>FORM\</auth-method\>
    <form-login-page\>/path</form-login-page\>
</login-config\>

As part of Single-sign-on migration, I need to remove user authentication and replace authentication with OKTA and still use LDAP authorization to get roles. I already completed OKTA Authentication but stuck with how to handle authorization. So, I am not understanding how to replace the form and just pass username and avoid j_security_check authentication. Please advise!
your text

Can you clarify how this ties into MongoDB Realm, which is the tag used on the question? Is this an Mongo Authentication question or a Realm Database question?

@Jay - Sorry, its not related to MongoDB, I tagged it accidentally, Ideally I mean JNDI Realm
